# Limiting area of page scroll on navigation click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the following jquery code to scroll to particular sections when a menu in the navigation tab is clicked. You must have well guessed by now that its a one page website. So coming further, the problem is that when the menu is clicked it scrolls to that particular DIV section but the header hides behind the menu's div. I mean it scrolls way too much up. I want to limit the level of scrolling. Say the it should stop 200px before than what it actually reaches a stop point now. Is it possible?

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').find('a').click(function(){
      var $href = $(this).attr('href');
      var $anchor = $($href).offset();
      var $li = $(this).parent('li');
      $li.addClass('active');
      $li.siblings().removeClass('active');
      $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: $anchor.top }, 1000);
      return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: As I recall isn't that what the `offset` is for?

Comment: can you write an answer with what you are trying to explain?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hard coding the header value, a better approach would be dynamically getting the height of header, so it won't create issues in mobile and other devices.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').find('a').click(function(){
          var $heightEx = $('.navbar').height(); // use your respective selector
          var $href = $(this).attr('href');
          var $anchor = $($href).offset();
          var $li = $(this).parent('li');
          $li.addClass('active');
          $li.siblings().removeClass('active');
          $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: ($anchor.top - $heightEx)  }, 1000);
          return false;
        });
    });
```

**EDIT**
This is the code I personally use

```
$("a").on('click', function(event) {
$heightEx = $('header').height(); 
if (this.hash !== "") {
  event.preventDefault();
  var hash = this.hash;
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: ($(hash).offset().top - $heightEx)
  }, 800);
}
```

});

Comment: Yeah perfect.. Thanks :)

Comment: You can mark the answer as correct if this helped you :)

Comment: Wait.. I just noticed that it works only when I go serially on menus. For example, say my menu is Home, About, Services so when I click them serially it works well but if I jump it doesn't works. With jump I mean say I am at Home and I jumped to Services and skipped About. So the serial clicking breaks here. And its not working again. I mean it again scrolls way too up when jumping then again if I go serially it works again. Why?

Comment: Was it behaving the same before adding the code or is it behaving like this now?

Comment: before adding your code it was always scrolling way to up no matter whether I clicked serially or jumped. But after adding your code it started working serially but jumping makes it scroll way to much up again like as if it was working when I hadn't inserted your code.

Comment: I have currently set the height manually to 220px. Its working well with jumping but serially 220px gives too much height. Any solution?

Comment: No idea whats wrong happening. Maybe you can create a jsFiddle if its easy for you or the other option is using the code I edited above. **Note** Above code won't do the active thing. Check if this works for you then I'll provide the code for active functionality too

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you need to change 'animate' scrollTop parameter:

```
 $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: $anchor.top - 200px }, 1000);
```

Comment: are you sure your code is correct? because its not working plus 200px is highlighted in red in my code editor (ATOM) which shows its an error.

Comment: Shouldn't `$anchor.top - 200px` be `$anchor.top - 200`?

Comment: Yes, my mistake, it should be integer 200.